# MySQL query results in the incorrect order

Tags: php, mysql, xml, sorting

So, I have a file that processes everything where a user types in a number, and that number is used to display an XML. This is part of the file:

```
while ($push = mysql_fetch_array($push_result)) {
    $item_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adva_".$push['Category']."s WHERE Id = '".$push['Id']."' ORDER BY Level");
    $item = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_result);
}
```

So, it's supposed to order by Level, but it doesn't, here is the XML (with only the relevant information):

```
<type>
    <Id>2537</Id>
    <Element>2</Element>
    <Level>10</Level>>
</type>
<type>
    <Id>2538</Id>
    <Element>2</Element>
    <Level>40</Level>>
</type>
<type>
    <Id>2540</Id>
    <Element>2</Element>
    <Level>70</Level>>
</type>
<type>
    <Id>2541</Id>
    <Element>2</Element>
    <Level>100</Level>>
</type>
<type>
    <Id>2542</Id>
    <Element>2</Element>
    <Level>130</Level>>
</type>
<type>
    <Id>2624</Id>
    <Element>1</Element>
    <Level>3</Level>>
</type>
<type>
    <Id>2625</Id>
    <Element>1</Element>
    <Level>28</Level>>
</type>
<type>
    <Id>2626</Id>
    <Element>1</Element>
    <Level>53</Level>>
</type>
<type>
    <Id>2627</Id>
    <Element>1</Element>
    <Level>78</Level>>
</type>
<type>
    <Id>2628</Id>
    <Element>1</Element>
    <Level>103</Level>>
</type>
<type>
    <Id>2629</Id>
    <Element>1</Element>
    <Level>128</Level>>
</type>
```

See, why does it sort by Id when I specifically told it not to? (I know that the code might be vulnerable, this is from 2010 I think, still only localhost).

Comment: mysql isn't doing any sorting, since you're doing a series of single-row-result queries. whatever is building your xml is doing this, or however you're storing the query results in php...

Comment: It's unclear, are you retrieving XML from the database, or generating it from query results? If the latter, have you stepped through the code and/or "echoed" the results to make sure they are coming out of order as opposed to xml generation functions internals causing a disordering. If the former, MySQL isn't going to sort the data in a blob.

Answer (score 1):

You are only fetching one element at a time inside your loop with `WHERE Id = '".$push['Id']."'`.  SQL can't sort one item.  So they probably end up in the same order they are in the $push array.  You want to collect all the ID's into an array and do a single query with `WHERE Id in (...)`.  (Do a search on SQL "in" statement).  Then your sort will work, and will also be much more efficient.